# Can't cat, gedit, vim, nano etc. /usr/bin/proxychains (just get jibberish)

Tags: binary, proxychains

I am using Ubuntu 5.15.0-57-generic and I see many people have a problem with proxychains where they get this error:

```
"ERROR: ld.so: object 'libproxychains.so.3' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored."
```

I get the same error and the fix is easy to look up. I just need to change the relative path in `/usr/bin/proxychains` to an absolute path. It seems like everyone else has no trouble with this, but no matter what I do the file looks the way most bin files look when you cat them:

```
@@@#%^$@%^&@#@@@@@@
```

Like that, if you know what I mean. The only thing that I could do was to add `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.3` to `/usr/bin/proxyresolv` but that did nothing.

I have tried to change the files in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` that might be relevant: `libproxy` is a directory that goes deeper than I want to mess with so I left it alone;
`libproxychains.so.3`, `libproxychains.so.3.0.0`, `libproxychains.so.4`, `libproxy.so.1`, and `libproxy.so.1.0.0` all give me gibberish, and `p11-kit-proxy.so` gave me the crazy screen pic I attached just for fun because I have never seen it and can't get out of it no matter what I do. (Also, as you can tell from the above, I tried to just use `proxychains4` when I saw someone say that it did not have this same issue with the relative path name, but no dice).

Anyway, I would love to get `proxychains` working, but I would love just as much to know why other people can cat `/usr/bin/proxychains` and get a nice and clear and editable `#!/bin/bash` file while I get nonsense.

Here is the main post that I was trying to follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63081456/error-ld-so-object-libproxychains-so-3-from-ld-preload-cannot-be-preloaded

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] and explain the main issue which is that you have problems with proxychains. The rest is all normal, you are attempting to cat an `.so` file which is a binary file and that's what binary data looks like when printed to the terminal. Those other people are using a system where `/usr/bin/proxychains` is a shell script, but yours is not. You can check this with `file /usr/bin/proxychains`.

Comment: Does it work if you just try the fix manually? Open a terminal and run `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.3 proxychains`

Comment: I tried the manual fix and the same thing happened, but something interesting happened when I ran file /usr/bin/proxychains. Here is what I got: /usr/bin/proxychains: symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/proxychains    I do not know how to use symbolic links, so I know I didn't make it. Do you think that might be the issue as to why mine does not seem to be a shell script? If not, do you have any guess as to why other people have a shell script version and mine is a binary? (Also thank you so much for your help. I really do appreciate it!)

Comment: I don't think there _is_ an issue, to be honest. The shell script is just a trivial wrapper that calls `proxychans`. But if `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.3 proxychains` didn't make a difference, then the "fix" isn't the right fix for you. Does `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.3` exist? Please [edit] your question, explain that you ran this command and it made no difference and also show us the output of `ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.*`.